# ¿como mantener el formato de un parrafo de word para poder usar regex?

Tags: c#, regex, formato, microsoft

mi problema es que tengo que copiar un texto desde word para poder darle un formato y agregarle algunas cosas mediante regex. pero cuando copio ciertos parrafos, se copian "con espacios" (los datos que copio los pego en un textbox ,uso c#).por lo tanto al hacer uso del regex

```
string patternespacios = @".+";
           string substitutionespacios = @"<br><br>$&";
           Regex regexespacios = new Regex(patternespacios, options);
           string resultespacios = regexespacios.Replace(resultnreak, substitutionespacios);
```

reconoce 3 párrafos en vez de 1
(si copio el texto de word y lo pego en regex101.com , tambien reconoce 3 parrafos en vez de 1) Ejemplo aqui https://regex101.com/r/N3GXjk/2

*parrafo 1*: <br<br El Ministerio de Salud (2017) en su Norma Técnica establece que el número mínimo de atenciones prenatales es de seis (14).
*parrafo 2* :<br<br Por tanto, es esencial que toda gestante cumpla con la cantidad necesaria de atenciones prenatales para una correcta supervisión del embarazo y la detección de posibles signos de alarma o complicaciones de manera oportuna; sin embargo, algunas de las pacientes no cumplen con la asistencia mínima por distintos motivos, los cuales han sido tratados en los siguientes estudios:
*parrafo 3* :<br<br Tovar y Gutiérrez (2019) en su investigación demostraron que los factores que se asociaron a la continuidad del control prenatal fueron el observar del personal de salud (OR=12,9; p=0,017), la asistencia temprana (OR=3,0; p=0,001), el trato bueno del personal administrativo (OR=2,2; p=0,015) y la resolución inmediata de inconvenientes durante la atención prenatal (OR=3,8; p=0,001)(15).

**lo que necesito es mantener el parrafo entero, por lo que el resultado debería ser este:**
<br<br El Ministerio de Salud (2017) en su Norma Técnica establece que el número mínimo de atenciones prenatales es de seis (14).
Por tanto, es esencial que toda gestante cumpla con la cantidad necesaria de atenciones prenatales para una correcta supervisión del embarazo y la detección de posibles signos de alarma o complicaciones de manera oportuna; sin embargo, algunas de las pacientes no cumplen con la asistencia mínima por distintos motivos, los cuales han sido tratados en los siguientes estudios:
Tovar y Gutiérrez (2019) en su investigación demostraron que los factores que se asociaron a la continuidad del control prenatal fueron el observar del personal de salud (OR=12,9; p=0,017), la asistencia temprana (OR=3,0; p=0,001), el trato bueno del personal administrativo (OR=2,2; p=0,015) y la resolución inmediata de inconvenientes durante la atención prenatal (OR=3,8; p=0,001)(15).

**¿Conocen alguna forma de hacer que el regex reconozca que es un solo párrafo? o en todo caso,poder eliminar esos espacios? (ya he probado eliminando los \t|\n|\v|\r)**

Comment: Los copias desde el word y donde los pegas?, y pon que lenguaje usas

Comment: @Japv , uso c#, lo que copio y pego lo meto dentro de un textbox. Fuera de eso, si copio y pego el texto de word y lo pongo en regex101.com para poder probar lo que estoy haciendo, el regex reconoce que son 3 parrafos en vez de 1. por ejemplo este : https://regex101.com/r/N3GXjk/2 ,lo que quiero es poder mantener el formato del word, que no se parta en 3 parrafos.

Comment: Hagamos esta primera prueba en vez de usar el textBox, usa el componente richTextBox, ya que este permite contenido no soportado por el textbox

Comment: Por otra parte copiar un texto en word es ctrl+C, copiar su formato es ctrl+shift+C, pegar es ctrl+V y pegar su formato es ctrl+Shift+V